# how to get a offline Django 1.6 documentation?

Tags: django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/faq/

when you download the  HTML one, and open the zip file,

[image]

you will see this:
[image]

is there something wrong? I've tried find the answer but no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well know issue. According to [a ticket about this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21400):

> It seems that the content of the documentation corresponds to the
>   right version and only the title is wrong

I also went to the `#django-dev` IRC channel and got a confirmation that the content of the file is indeed correct - the only thing that is broken is the title itself.

This means you can safely use the file you downloaded.